# Socket connection refused in Client Code

Tags: java, sockets

The below program causes this issue

**EDITED:**

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
public class smtpClient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
// declaration section:
// smtpClient: our client socket
// os: output stream
// is: input stream
        Socket smtpSocket = null;  
        DataOutputStream os = null;
        DataInputStream is = null;
// Initialization section:
// Try to open a socket on port 25 : step 1
// Try to open input and output streams: step 2
        try {
            smtpSocket = new Socket("192.168.1.2", 1024);
            os = new DataOutputStream(smtpSocket.getOutputStream());
            is = new DataInputStream(smtpSocket.getInputStream());
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Don't know about host: hostname");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: hostname");
        }
// If everything has been initialized then we want to write some data
// to the socket we have opened a connection to on port 25
    if (smtpSocket != null && os != null && is != null) {
            try {
// The capital string before each colon has a special meaning to SMTP
// you may want to read the SMTP specification, RFC1822/3
        os.writeBytes("HELO\n");    
                os.writeBytes("MAIL From: k3is@fundy.csd.unbsj.ca\n");
                os.writeBytes("RCPT To: k3is@fundy.csd.unbsj.ca\n");
                os.writeBytes("DATA\n");
                os.writeBytes("From: k3is@fundy.csd.unbsj.ca\n");
                os.writeBytes("Subject: testing\n");
                os.writeBytes("Hi there\n"); // message body
                os.writeBytes("\n.\n");
        os.writeBytes("QUIT");
// keep on reading from/to the socket till we receive the "Ok" from SMTP,
// once we received that then we want to break.
                String responseLine;
                while ((responseLine = is.readLine()) != null) {
                    System.out.println("Server: " + responseLine);
                    if (responseLine.indexOf("Ok") != -1) {
                      break;
                    }
                }
// clean up:
// close the output stream
// close the input stream
// close the socket
                os.close();
                is.close();
                smtpSocket.close();   
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                System.err.println("Trying to connect to unknown host: " + e);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("IOException:  " + e);
            }
        }
    }           
}
```

Console Log :

```
Couldn't get I/O for the connection to: hostname
```

The program I took is from :
http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-1996/jw-12-sockets.html?page=4

I have already tried modifying  the port from 25 to 1024
I am running it on my local PC, so I am admin on this system, but not sure if there is any default firewall issue(running this in eclipse on windows 7)

**As per your comments below :** DO I need to make a listner, which mean to say a Server Socket, which will listen to smtp client requests

Comment: Is there anything listening on port 1024 on that ip-address?

Comment: just wondering - is there anything which actually listens on that port and specified IP?

Comment: 1024 is reserved port anyway...

Comment: it's not actually reserver, case is that lower 1024 ports are allowed to be used only by root

Comment: @Zavior Nope, only up to (and including) port 1023 are reserved.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg https://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.txt

Comment: again.. reserve in that matter is really wrong word, they just in most of cases have particular meaning, but nobody stops you to use them as soon as you know what you are doing..

Comment: You are correct. I wouldn't use it though :)

Comment: well, may be one day you decide to write your own web or mail server =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer is: according to details what you have provided, there is no listener running or machine with specified IP and port number.

UPD: then you are trying to connect to somewhere you do have to be sure that there is something which listens on other side, either writing your own server code or by using a 3rd party server/code to provide certain service on a port number you are trying to reach.

Why would you expect that there is a mail server running on machine with an address you've provided?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like some other program is using port 1024.

Try a different port.