# Android: Connection Refused on Socket Declaration

Tags: android, sockets, connection

I hope this hasn't been answered before, but after a quick google I didn't find any answers.

I have an Android phone which is trying to connect to my laptop over Wifi to retrieve information from a server app running on the laptop. Note: the application is deployed onto my mobile phone.

SERVERIP = "10.0.0.100"
SERVERPORT = 1337

This worked a week ago on my friends Wifi when his PC was running the server, but on my PC and my Wifi the folowing happens:

```
    try {
        Log.d(tag, "Declaring socket...");              //print to log for debugging purposes
        socket = new Socket(SERVERIP, SERVERPORT);  //declare the socket
        Log.d(tag, "Attempting login...");          //print to the log for debugging purposes

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());

        out.println("MLI$" + username.getText().toString() + "$" + password.getText().toString());
        out.flush();

        error.setText("Sent connection string...");

        if(!in.readLine().equals("NLI$Login Failed"))
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewTimetableCycle.class);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
        else
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Invalid username/password combination", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            error.setText("Invalid username/password combination");

        }

    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        Log.d(tag, "UnknownHostException");
        error.setText("UnknownHostException");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d(tag, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());
        error.setText("");
    }
```

Output in the log:

```
Declaring socket...
08-14 20:25:10.065: D/LoginActivity(21045): IOException: failed to connect to /10.0.0.100 (port 1337): connect failed: ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused)
```

The catch blocks are not executed and the connection is refused as I create the socket. As for the server, there is no activity whatsoever - it doesn't detect any connections.

So what I would like to know is, is this a network error? I tried forwarding the port to no avail. I came accross the following stackoverflow queries which didn't help me much:

[Android Socket connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2425774/android-socket-connection-refused)

[Socket connection refused in Client Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18147962/socket-connection-refused-in-client-code)

Comment: Sure looks like the catch block is executed to me. You aren't 'declaring' the socket at that line of code, you are *creating* it. 'Connection refused' means that either nothing is listening at that IP:port or there is a non-cooperative firewall in the way.

Comment: Definitely happens when you create the socket `socket = new Socket(...)`. Always check these two things: Can you `ping` your phone from the Laptop? If so, is any server listening on the laptop on port 1337? Answering these two question do not solve all possible issues you can have, but it's a start. Let us know, what you found.

Comment: @EJP: You may be right, and the IOException catch block might be called... I will check and get back to you. If that is the case, however, that means that my phone thinks I am giving it an invalid port or IP address right?

Comment: @jboi: I could ping my phone from my laptop, and I don't think that there is a firewall blocking the connection unless it is on the router. I will check out my router's firewall

Comment: i m having the same issue, please let me know if you found the solution